# What is the meaning of Python's philosophy "never is often better than *right* now"

Tags: python

I don't quite understand the second sentence here from [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Now is better than never.
>   Although never is often better than *right* now.

Can anyone explain it or give an example?

Comment: You should ask [Tim Peters](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2705542/tim-peters).  If I'm right, that is the same person who wrote it. :)

Comment: Better to realise that your problem can't be solved in a certain way, than implement a quick solution that doesn't quite work but appears to. @iCodez yup - seems an ideal question for Tim - wonder if he ever thought he might get the chance to answer a question on `import this` :)

Comment: That would make a good question for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Strangely, programmers is not listed in the close menu, so let's go with "opinion based".

Comment: @thg435, I've been surprised at the number of "opinion based" questions that can be solved unambiguously by searching the public record.

Comment: @georg A question on the same issue has been asked in the meantime on programmers as well, but it’s been closed with the same reason https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310015/for-python-programming-and-being-pythonic-why-never-is-often-better-than-righ

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is a two parter:

> Now is better than never

Don't spend too much time planning and pre-optimising; get something down that does the job and iterate on it (or: fix that issue now rather than putting it off).

> Never is often better than *right* now

But do put some thought into it, so you don't head off down a path that later means there's no graceful way back (see also: [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)).

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine that the philosophy means that it is better to think of a solution rather than simply forestalling the inevitable (and causing problems later).

However, it is also better to think about what solution you will do first - don't write 'quick hacks' to solve the problem at hand.

So, It's best to fix that problem sooner rather than later, but don't immediately code whatever comes to mind, instead, think about that first and what ramifications your fix might have.